# toggle state for multiple elements in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am using UncontrolledCollapse component from reactstrap and I have multiple static elements to control.

By default I need all the elements to be open by default ( Not collapsed ), on click related individual element will be collapsed.

But I have only one state to manage the behavior, which will open and close all the panels on click.

**Below is the code:**

```
import { UncontrolledCollapse, Button, CardBody, Card } from "reactstrap";

class ProductList extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: true
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="filter-options-title"
          id="toggler"
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >
          Test
        </div>
        <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler" isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
          <div className="filter-options-content">Test Content</div>
        </UncontrolledCollapse>
        <div
          className="filter-options-title"
          id="toggler1"
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >
          Test
        </div>
        <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler1" isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
          <div className="filter-options-content">Test Content</div>
        </UncontrolledCollapse>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate keys in your state. Because currently you're using the same state prop for both of the elements, so if you close one both get closed. I also changed the toggle method (made is accept which elements gets toggled).

```
import { UncontrolledCollapse, Button, CardBody, Card } from 'reactstrap';

class ProductList extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            toggler: true,
            toggler1: true,
        }

    }
    toggle(toggler) {
        let togglerStatus = this.state[toggler]; //check the status of the toggle you clicked
        this.setState({
            [toggler]: !togglerStatus // change the status only for the toggle you clicked
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="filter-options-title" id="" onClick={() => this.toggle('toggler')}>
                    Test
                </div>
                <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler" isOpen={this.state['toggler']}>
                    <div className="filter-options-content">
                        Test Content
                    </div>
                </UncontrolledCollapse>
                <div className="filter-options-title" id="toggler1" onClick={() => this.toggle('toggler1')}>
                    Test
                </div>
                <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler1" isOpen={this.state['toggler1']}>
                    <div className="filter-options-content">
                        Test Content
                </div>
                </UncontrolledCollapse>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I can create multiple state, but if I have more than 5 or 10 elements to toggle then I have to create 10 different states ?

Comment: @H.Husain In the `state`, create an array of objects with 2 properties . `text` and `toggle`. Add `Test Content 1` etc to the `text` property. Loop through this array and create multiple `UncontrolledCollapse` and set the `toggle` property based on the index

Comment: @adiga : that is my problem, I cannot loop through UncontrolledCollapse because I have different content in each of the UncontrolledCollapse element.

Comment: @H.Husain That's why I said 2 properties. One `text` property to keep `Test Content` etc. Another to keep the `toggle` status. If you have further difference between each `UncontrolledCollapse `, you can create more properties in each obejct of the array